# What restrictions can be placed on the 4-momentum of off-shell particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, virtual-particles

I'm interested in the values that the 4-momenta of off-shell particles are allowed to take.

I suppose if one intends to eventually have these particles interact in a way that generates an on-shell particle, and 3-momentum is conserved at the vertex, then the sum of the 3-momenta of all the off-shell particles must be finite. Can the 3-momentum of an off-shell particle be complex or imaginary?

What about the energy, does this need to be real?

Say on-shell particles have only positive energy values in this system, are the off-shell energy values also restricted to being positive?

Does this relate to the Dirac "spectrum property" that I have seen mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

An off-shell 4-momentum $p$ is *still a real-valued vector*, "off-shell" just means it does not fulfill the correct mass-energy relation for the system it belongs to, i.e. $p^2 = m^2$.

So, no, a 4-momentum cannot be complex, imaginary, or infinite, even off-shell. It's a real-valued 4-vector.

Comment: When we use contour integration and the residue theorem to evaluate a loop in a Feynman diagram does this not, at least temporarily, treat the 4 vector as complex?

Comment: @TheoreticalPerson There are indeed methods to evaluate real integrals by complex integration methods such as contour integrals, but that does not imply that we should *physically* think of the quantity as complex-valued. The integrals we write down, coming from physics, are real, what mathematics you use to evaluate them is your business and has no impact on the physics.

Comment: well yes, except in as much as the mathematics is not immune to the physics. Integrating over all possible momenta in a loop is only done because off-shell momenta don't obey the dispersion relation. If I had other constraints on off-shell momenta perhaps the integration could be simplified by them. Does it make sense why I was intrested?